# Can you make a variable image depending on page number using one master

Tags: adobe-indesign, xml

I've searched in vain for at method for changing a footer logo dependent on page number. I want a different image on every other even page but as I am already using a number of master pages to different chapters for the book, I want to be able to vary the footer without having to apply different master pages.

Could using XML in combination with text variables do the trick?

Comment: would it be an option to just put an empty frame on the master and `Shift`+`Ctrl/Option`+click it on the actual pages, and then place the image?

Comment: Way to many pages. And what happens when I add pages inbetween?

Comment: Can probably achieve this with some scripting. I think this will get you started: https://forums.adobe.com/message/6120671

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would take a custom script, no question, because it requires conditional logic, which you don't have available with XML.

Your best bet would be to ask on the Adobe [InDesign Scripting forum](https://forums.adobe.com/community/indesign/indesign_scripting), where lots of very helpful folks hang out. (Scripters in general are some of the most helpful people you'll come across on the interwebs.)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'll check it out, and come back if I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit funky, but you can make a **4-page Master**.
Thus your Master includes two spreads, one for each of your logos.

The trouble is that the Indesign wants to keep **facing pages**, so I had to manually drag them in place. Otherwise you only see the first two pages.

Once you have the 4 you can duplicate them to fill your page count.

[image]

The other problem is that you might have to allow more page size for **bleed**, as there would be no bleed between the two spreads in this set-up. *(on the middle edge between spreads)*

Comment: Hmm. Seems bit of a work-around for me. I think I'll pursue the use of scripting.